# Probability of Brownian Motion

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, limsup-and-liminf

I've studied a proof from the book *An Introduction to Stochastic Differential Equations* concerning the nowhere differentiability of the Brownian motion and I'm stuck at the following proof:[image]

In the second point, I don't understand the third inequality

$$\liminf_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n P(A_{M,n}^i) \leq  \liminf_{n\to\infty} n\cdot P(|W(1/n)|\leq Mn^{-\gamma})^N.$$

Which theorem in the probability theory was applied in this inequality?

Comment: $A^i_{M, n}$ is a sum of $N$ independent events, and $W(\frac{j+1}{n})-W(\frac{j}{n})$ has distribution the same as $W(\frac{1}{n})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the inequality in question follows from the following equality:
$$
\mathbb P(A^i_{M,n})=\mathbb P(|W(1/n)|\leq Mn^{-\gamma})^N.
$$
It is a direct consequence of the **independence of increments** property of the Brownian motion combined with **stationarity of increments**.

The former property implies that the events
$$
\left\{\omega\colon \left|W\bigl(\frac{j+1}{n}\bigr)-W\bigl(\frac{j}{n}\bigr)\right|\leq Mn^{-\gamma}\right\},\qquad j=i,\ldots,i+N-1
$$
are independent. The latter means that
$$
W\bigl(\frac{j+1}{n}\bigr)-W\bigl(\frac{j}{n}\bigr)
$$
all have the same distribution, regardless of $j$, and equal to the distribution that results when $j=0$.

Combining these two properties yields the equality I mentioned at the start.